# calculating recurrence relation T(n) = n+ T(n/2)

Tags: recurrence

[image]
**T(n) = n + T(n/2)**

= n + n/2 + T(n/4)

= n + n/2 + n/4 + T(n/8)

= n + n/2 + n/4 + ... + n/(2^(k-1)) + T(n/2^k)

->>>

and I don't know how to go on to get big Oh formula.
please help me

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it is not a programming question. Try http://math.stackexchange.com

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm assuming there's some kind of initial condition like `T(1) = 0` that you are not telling us.

If so, the answer is `O(log n)`.

Think about how you would work out `T(2)`, `T(4)`, `T(8)`, `T(16)` etc. Each one requires just one extra step.

```
T(1) = T(2^0) calls the method recursively 0 times.
T(2) = T(2^1) calls the method recursively 1 time
T(4) = T(2^2) calls the method recursively 2 times
T(8) = T(2^3) calls the method recursively 3 times
```

In other words, the number of steps is the power. This means that you have to take logarithms to get the answer.

Comment: hmm I am not sure T(1) = 0 but when I think about "calls" it makes sense, I am using the math calculation to solve it, but I get O(n) I am now sure why it is O(log n). I will post my calculation

Comment: but T(n) is not only about how many time calling the recursive calls.. I guess

Comment: @IAMBEAST You're right, it isn't, but in this case it's the same because the only other operation is the addition, which is `O(1)`. Your calculation is faulty in 2 ways. Firstly you seem to be confused about whether you are working out `T(n)` or the time complexity. Secondly, you can't use the sum to infinity of a geometric sequence - presumably `n` is an integer, not a real number that can be halved arbitrarily many times.

Comment: no the formula not for infinity that part you can find it in wikipedia, when you calculate the first term to n-1 term you can use the a*(1-r^n)/(1-r).

Comment: @IAMBEAST You're right. That was a stupid thing to say. The other point is still valid though. All this `n/2 + n/4` stuff is completely irrelevant - that's about the *value* of `T(n)`, not the time it takes to compute it.

Comment: oh okay yeah honestly I don't know what is difference between time complexity and T(n) .. hmm if I say calculating recursion relation formula, does it means solving for T(n)?

Comment: @IAMBEAST I'm not sure what the question is now. I'd assumed that `T(n)` was the function you were trying to compute. It now looks like `T` is means to be the time. I think you need to post the *exact* problem you were given.

Comment: I think my question is not that 100% clear but it has the point I need the Big Oh equation by T(n) formula.